# generate dynamic ids for <td> in foreach loop

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have three bean classes Animal , Dog and Pug (names changed for an example)

```
class Animal {
List <Dog> dogList;
}

class Dog {
price;
List<Pug> PugList;
}

class Pug {
color;
weight;
}
```

below is the jsp page :

```
<c:forEach var="animal" items="${Animal.dogList}"  varStatus="outerLoop"> 

   <c:forEach var="dog" items="${animal.PugList}"  varStatus="innerLoop">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label id="pugColorLabel">color :</label>
            <input id="colorid${innerloop.index +1}" name="color" value="${dog.color}" />   
            <input id="weightid${innerloop.index +1}" name="weight" value="${dog.weight}" />    
        </td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>

            <td>
                <label id="dogPriceLabel">price :</label>
                <input id="dogPriceid${outerLoop.index +1}" name="price" value="${animal.price}"/>
            </td>
 </c:forEach>
```

I have a page where I have to display color and weight of all the Pugs including the price of the dog and there are 7 dog objects (static number) and 1-5 dog objects will have only one pug objects (static number) but 6th and 7th dog will have
 two pugs each (again static number).

**Here is my problem :**

so the `<c:forEach>` logic is working fine but the ids are not coming the way I want, I want all the pugs id different so that i can fetch the values by ids.
 the above code snippet will always give me pug attributes - colorid and weightid as 1 (colorid1 and weightid1) because 1-5 dog instance are having only one pug instance.
 and 5th and 6th dog instance are having two pugs each so they too should give me different ids so that i can fetch their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use both outerloop and innerloop to make unique ids, you can use `colorId${outerloop.index+1}{innerloop.index+1}`
now you will get ids as, colorId11, colorId21...colorId61,colorId62.. etc

Answer (score 0):

Just for a simple code, if you don't wanna get the index [0], you can use de property '***count***', making 'innerLoop.count' instead 'innerLoop.index' for example.
the property *index* starts in [0], the property *count* starts in [1].

```
<input id="colorid${innerloop.count}" name="color" value="${dog.color}"/> 
<input id="weightid${innerloop.count}" name="weight" value="${dog.weight}"/>
```